# Uploading file geodatabase to CARTO

Tags: carto, file-geodatabase

I'm new to Carto and I'm trying yo upload a gdb file but I cannot see the option in the display formats.

How can I upload it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple read of the [carto documentation](https://carto.com/developers/import-api/guides/importing-geospatial-data/#supported-geospatial-data-formats) let you know how to do it :

> **FileGeodatabase**
>
> File Geodatabase (GDB) is a proprietary Esri format for spatial data. The GDB format is a directory with a .gdb
> extension containing the data files, so for download and upload a zip
> file containing the directory is used, either with a .zip or a
> .gdb.zip extension. Each layer (up to 50) in the GDB file will be
> imported as a separate CARTO table.

Comment: I actually read that, thanks very much!

Comment: Hi again, I cannot chose .gdb. I can see all the formats available like csv, Jason,shp, excel nut not gdb

Comment: Does this : https://carto.com/help/tutorials/data-management/#importing-data help ?

Comment: Try dragging and dropping.